# What is equivalent of smbpasswd -a on OS X Server? How to add Local Network Directory Users in Samba?

Tags: samba, mac-osx-server, file-sharing

When a user is created on a Mac OS X Server 5.2 (Sierra), it can be created either on:

Local Directory (which is simply a local user)

or

Local Network Directory (which is actually Open Directory Services (LDAP))

The problem is that those users in Local Network Directory (LDAP) cannot add their passwords in Samba, so they cannot get authenticated over SMB and obviously cannot use the shares from their Windows computers.

But the same Windows computers can connect to the SMB shares when the user is a local user on the OS X Server.
The same Local Network Directory (LDAP) users can connect to the file sharing service over AFP from Mac computers.

How can I somehow store/add Local Network Directory users' passwords to the Samba? In Linux one needs to use smbpasswd -a to add a user to Samba authentication, but how is it done in Mac OS X 5.2 (Sierra)?

Many Thanks!